# Capture screen -- chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia fails -- PNacl extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I'm trying to use the [desktopCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) in the following manner.

```
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
            ["screen", "window"], onAccessApproved);
```

chrome.desktopCapture shows as undefined when I set a breakpoint and inspect it. Permissions in my manifest file are as follows:-

```
"permissions": ["desktopCapture", "notifications" ]
```

Common causes for failure of this API are listed [here](https://dart-gde.github.io/chrome_gen.dart/ext/chrome.desktopCapture/ChromeDesktopCapture.html) as

- a permission is missing in the application's manifest.json file
- the API is defined on a newer version of Chrome then the current runtime
  docs inherited from ChromeApi

And I don't have those problems.

- My Chrome version is `43.0.2357.124 m`
- Pepper version is 43

FYI, I am trying to develop a Chrome extension to capture the screen using PNacl, and have borrowed from the [media_stream_video example downloaded from here](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/sdk/examples).  But I haven't even gotten to sending a message to the pexe side yet. I'm still stuck at `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia` returning undefined.

Comment: what's happening - error message, stream invalid?

Comment: another way to capture current visible tab https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab

Comment: The exact error logged in Console is --
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chooseDesktopMedia' of undefined"

Essentially this statement doesn't work 
'chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia( "screen", "window"], onAccessApproved);'

because chrome.desktopCapture shows as undefined..  From that it feels like the permission to capture the screen "desktopCapture" has not been granted.

Comment: @AmitG - from the description of captureVisibleTab, it seems like its used for image capture.. I'm trying to record the screen and save it to a Chrome file (I understand that I can't access the local filesystem from an extension, but that I can store to a "Chrome file").

Comment: You forgot another failure condition. Most APIs are not available from content scripts. Is that your problem? Also, your question has nothing to do with NaCl side of things, you may want to edit that out as it's irrelevant.

Comment: Hi @Xan, Are you sure it doesn't have anything to do with NacL?  The reason I ask - here's what I did:-  
  
1. Tested [original desktopCapture example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/desktop-capture).  
2. Added the pexe stuff - makefile, media_stream_video.cc, common.js  
3. Modified index.html to include common.js  
  
And the call to `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia` stopped working.  
  
[Modified code here](https://github.com/juguar/desktopCapture-modified).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia` from the background script running in the context of the extension. [This Sample](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/getScreenMedia/tree/master/chrome-extension-sample) shows a simple method to use the extension to get screen media.

Keep in mind that this is callback based, so you get access to the stream id from the callback.

This runs in the context of your page (see full example [here](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/getScreenMedia/blob/master/getscreenmedia.js)):

```
    // check that the extension is installed
    if (sessionStorage.getScreenMediaJSExtensionId) {
        // send a message to your extension requesting media
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(sessionStorage.getScreenMediaJSExtensionId,
            {type:'getScreen', id: 1}, null,
            function (data) {
                if (data.sourceId === '') { // user canceled
                    // handle error
                } else {
                    constraints.video.mandatory.chromeMediaSourceId = data.sourceId;
                    getUserMedia(constraints, callback);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

And this run in the context of your extension (see full example [here](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/getScreenMedia/blob/master/chrome-extension-sample/background.js)):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function (message, sender, callback) {
    switch(message.type) {
        case 'getScreen':
            var pending = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(message.options || ['screen', 'window'],
                                                               sender.tab, function (streamid) {
                // communicate this string to the app so it can call getUserMedia with it
                message.type = 'gotScreen';
                message.sourceId = streamid;
                callback(message);
                return false;
            });
            return true; // retain callback for chooseDesktopMedia result
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will try. FYI, here's [original example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/desktop-capture) I started with.

Here's my [modified code](https://github.com/juguar/desktopCapture-modified). My mods were -
1. Tested original desktopCapture.. working fine.
2. Added - `common.js`, `background.js`, `media_stream_video.cc`, `Makefile`
3. To `index.html`, added `<script src="common.js"></script>`

That's all I did, and the call to `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen", "window"], onAccessApproved);` stopped working.

Comment: This does not work still, if iFrame is trying to share desktop.

Comment: @jster, do you mind sharing the final code you got, I am stuck for the past week trying to build a prototype that do what described

Comment: If you just want to capture the Desktop as an image, is there an easier way to do this? There's always https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture#type-CaptureOptions, but this only works for Chrome *tabs*