# Can a Chrome extension take a screenshot of the entire desktop?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There are a number of extensions that demonstrate taking a screenshot of the web page currently displayed.

Is it possible for any extension to take a screenshot of the entire display, not just of what's being displayed in Chrome itself? If so, how can it exactly be done by the extension?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture

Comment: this is already covered in a few questions like http://stackoverflow.com/q/30906689/2213940